# What condition is missing here?

Tags: distributions

```
distE=NormalDistribution[0,s];
TransformedDistribution[(e/s)^2,e\[Distributed]distE,Assumptions->s>0]
```

The transformed distribution is not `ChiSquareDistribution[1]`. But the following is `ChiSquareDistribution[1]`. What condition is missing in the above that is preventing mathematica to say it is chisquare?

```
TransformedDistribution[x^2,x\[Distributed]NormalDistribution[]]
```

I tried the following to no success.

```
TransformedDistribution[Piecewise[{{e^2/s^2,s>0},{0,True}}],e\[Distributed]distE]
```

Answer (score 1):

But it is a `ChiSquareDistribution[1]`.  It just isn't labeled as such.  All of the associated functions (`RandomVariate`, `Expectation`, etc.) work as expected as if it were an appropriately labeled `ChiSquareDistribution[1]`.

Here is why (but this doesn't answer your question as to what condition to add):

```
PDF[ChiSquareDistribution[1], x]
```

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{x}} & x>0 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$

```
distE = NormalDistribution[0, s];
td = TransformedDistribution[(e/s)^2, e \[Distributed] distE, Assumptions -> {s > 0}]
PDF[td, x]
```

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{x}} & x>0 \\
 0 & x<0 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$

So the resulting PDF's are in slightly different forms.

You can get the PDF in the desired form by the following:

```
pdf = PDF[td, x]
pdf[[2]] = 0;
```